# What must be added to the cmder's .gitconfig file to run sublimemerge as a git mergetool?

Tags: git, cmder

I was eager to try out the new git mergetool integration, but I ran into a problem:

I’m running Windows 10 and installed the SublimeMerge package. I'm also using cmder instead of windows CLI as it also comes up with git integration (*no need to install git bash additionally*). I have searched enough but unable to find a solution.

I have added C:\Program Files\Sublime Merge to my %PATH% variable.
And updated global git configuration settings

```
git config --global merge.tool smerge
```

But according to official git mergetool documentation:

> Use the merge resolution program specified by . Valid values include emerge, gvimdiff, kdiff3, meld, vimdiff, and tortoisemerge. Run git mergetool --tool-help for the list of valid  settings.

When I run the command, I am missing smerge under mergetools, refer screenhot below :
[cmder console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3oqI.png)

I strongly belive my changes are not being refected in cmder's gitconfig file but at the same time there should be a way to do it.

Comment: The config can't contain arbitrary program, only one from expected list. You may try to either rename (link) smerge to one of the supported tool names, or create some service tool, which would take one arguments and run smerge with converted arguments